# xcode - Cocoapods stopped working after OS upgrade

Tags: xcode, cocoapods

After upgrading to OS X Yosemite, attempting to install pods gives me this error.

```
/Library/Ruby/Site/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require': cannot load such file -- xcodeproj/prebuilt/universal.x86_64-darwin14-2.0.0/xcodeproj_ext (LoadError)
    from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/xcodeproj-0.16.1/lib/xcodeproj/ext.rb:6:in `rescue in <top (required)>'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/xcodeproj-0.16.1/lib/xcodeproj/ext.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/xcodeproj-0.16.1/lib/xcodeproj.rb:30:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-0.32.1/lib/cocoapods.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-0.32.1/bin/pod:32:in `<top (required)>'
    from /usr/bin/pod:23:in `load'
    from /usr/bin/pod:23:in `<main>'
```

I have tried uninstalling cocoapods and installing it with no luck. I get this error upon trying to install cocoapods.

```
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Errno::EEXIST)
    File exists @ dir_s_mkdir - /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems
```

In xcode-preferences-locations I am not given an option to change Command Line tools to anything lower than Xcode 6.3...

Any ideas how to fix this?